# Why am I getting Numeric Value Out of Range Error when running query with pyodbc, with parameters?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm connecting to a database with pyodbc, and then trying to run the following query, with parameters, but am getting the subsequent error. When I replace the first '?' with the value 140014, the error disappears.

```
data1 = cursor.execute('''SELECT SUM(A2TAMT),
                                'BENEFITS',
                                'PO BOX 5',
                                '',
                                'DES MOINES',
                                'IA',
                                '50331-0502'
                        FROM ARLIBF.ARM002
                        WHERE A2STAT = ' '
                            AND A2ACCT = ?
                            AND A2TTYP = 'M'
                            AND A2PDAT BETWEEN ? AND ?
                            AND A2ACCT NOT IN (SELECT T1VALU FROM TAB001 WHERE T1TABL = 'COMX' AND T1VALU != '')
                        GROUP BY A2ACCT
                       ''', '140014', '20000101', '20211231').fetchall()
```

> DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Column 1: Numeric value out of range. (30160) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: are you connecting to Access ?

Comment: What do you see if you `print(list(col.type_name for col in cursor.columns(table="ARM002", schema="ARLIBF") if col.column_name == "A2ACCT"))` ?

Comment: @eshirvana - It looks like they are connecting to an IBM AS/400 ("System i")